# Want to convert Colour of h3 tag heading in html string using swift

Tags: swift, ios7, xcode7

I have an html string which i have to show in text view i have converted it in NSMutableString but in that string there are multiple headings are coming . i want to change the colour of that headings in blue.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply color in h3 tag like this way

```
let htmlString: String = "<html><body> <h3><font color=black>Some html string</font></h3> </body></html>"

let temphtmlString : NSString = (htmlString as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("color=black", withString: "color=blue")


  let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
                data: temphtmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil)
txtView.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: html string is coming from server and the heading tag colour is black their.

Comment: You can replace html string using **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString**